# Is that possible to run apps in the iOS app if user close it?

Tags: ios, mobile, background, embedded, location

For example: an alarm app, if user close this iOS alarm app, will this app still possible to alarm user at the time they set?

For another example: an LBS app, if user close this iOS LBS app, will this app still possible to detect user's current location? Not the location that last time user opened.

I know it's possible in Android, but can't find any way to do in iOS. Please let me know which library I can research to achieve that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

iOS apps can perform limited functions in the background.  They are documented in the App Programming Guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

You can set alarms by using local push notifications. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

You can track location by using the Location Updates background mode.